# SQL: Ordering by how much greater than something is?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have two `datetime` fields here: `actual_delivery` and `scheduled_delivery`

What I want to do an ORDER BY on is how much great `actual_delivery` is than `scheduled_delivery`.

I'm using MySQL locally and PostgreSQL in production, so it needs to work for both.

Comment: "I'm using MySQL locally and PostgreSQL in production" - because...?

Comment: @Mark, because he wants things portable :P

Comment: @Mark I'm personally a MySQL guy, but the client's server is using PostgreSQL (which I have no control over). Most things port fine between the two, but I knew this might be an edge case so wanted to specify that it needed to work between both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT actual_delivery, scheduled_delivery, actual_delivery - scheduled_delivery as difference FROM tablename ORDER BY difference`

Comment: Perfect. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight. :)

Answer (score 4):

If I were doing it in SQL Server I'd calculate `DATEDIFF(actual_delivery, scheduled_deliver) AS [DeliveryDifference]` then order by that computed column.

A quick search indicates there's a `datediff` function in MySql but the syntax may be slightly different in PostgreSQL so you may have to create your own function there.